# I am trying to make a agario clone server on a different website. But I keep getting this error

Tags: html

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://error404.000webhost.com/?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.agario.netii.net' is therefore not allowed access.

You can go to agario.netii.net and go to console in inspect element to see the error yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to copy website without owning a server you can copy website using "**iframe**"

```
<iframe src="http://website.com" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
Your browser doesn't support iframes
```

And it should work